# GCMRegistrar Crash with ECPN plugin for unity android

Tags: push-notification, unity-game-engine

I encountered a severe problem with the ECPN plugin (push notification) for android. As client needs it these days and push notification is my last hurdle......

OK, I changed your plugin quite a bit, just to work with my own purpose. It seems that my Samsung S4 and Sony Xperia got crash whenever gcm.jar is used, for example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);


Intent i = getIntent();
Boolean isRegistration = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isRegistration ");
/*
if(!isRegistration) {
// Unregister device
GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
} else {
// Carry on with registration
String SENDER_ID = i.getStringExtra("senderID");

// Checking device and manifest dependencies

*/
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);


// GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

// Get GCM registration id
//final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
/*
// Check if regid already presents
if (regId.equals("")) {
// Registration is not present, register now with GCM
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
// Send ID to Unity
sendConfirmRegistration(regId);
// if registeredOnServer flag is not set, send info to Unity
if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(this, true);
}
}
}
*/
finish();
return;
}
```

The procedure crashes at the bold line. Any idea why it is so ?

My bundleID is com.redcross.redcross, below is my manifest file for GCM portion.

```
<!-- GCM java -->
<activity
android:name="com.redcross.redcross.GCMJava"
android:label="@string/app_name" > <!-- android:name must coincide with GCMJava package name + .GCMJava-->
</activity>

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastR eceiver" androidermission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND " > 
<intent-filter>
<!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEI VE" />
<!-- Receives the registration id. -->
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGIS TRATION" />
<category android:name="com.redcross.redcross" /> <!-- android:name must coincide with GCMJava package name -->
</intent-filter> </receiver>
<service android:name="com.redcross.redcross.GCMIntentServi ce" /> <!-- android:name must coincide with GCMJava package name + .GCMIntentService-->
<!-- end -->
```

And I tried putting classes.jar, gcm.jar and android.jar around in unity asset folder => plugins => android and referenced inside or outside GCMJava.jar, it simply doesn't work out... Worked two whole days already...

Really appreciate your help ...

Comment: You have some extra spaces in the manifest (example: `RECEI VE`). Do you have them in the real manifest too, or just here?

Comment: Hi Eran, thanks for the help. For some weird reason it just appeared here. For any other who encountered this issue, I solved this and found it related to the device we were testing on. The port of GCM may sometimes be taken by other firewall or softwares.